# Youtube live streams in Android Webview are jittery

Tags: android, flash, webview, youtube

I am having a lot of trouble trying to play some youtube videos inside an Android Webview. I search everywhere but cannot find a solution that works.

I am using the following code:

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
//Setup Webview
WebChromeClient client= new WebChromeClient();
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(client);

mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("www.youtube.com", "<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"640\" height=\"385\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/JEkbk-xDmZE?html5=1\" frameborder=\"0\">\n</iframe>", "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

The problem seems to be only with certain streams like this one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEkbk-xDmZE

The sound is great but the video is very slow, like 1 frame per second. unwatchable.

But if I use this stream: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDFIYKmNw9Q

It works perfectly fine.

What is the difference between these live streams and how do I get the first one to play properly?
Also I should mention that sometimes the first one DOES play just fine. I am not able to figure out why it sometimes plays and other times doesn't. I've tried creating a new project with pretty much just a Webview and a Factory Reset device to eliminate any settings that may be effecting this but I still get the problem.

Comment: did you find working solution for your problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've struggled with YouTube in general, trying to get it to work on android. Why certain videos lag is beyond me, but it might be different quality settings and limited bandwidth thus its buffering.

Hopefully one of the options below might help if it's not a buffering issue.

Currently, with WebView you use either use an IFrame or the YouTube API. Otherwise you can use the GData API to get the RSTP link to the video for use in a VideoView. Finally you can use an Intent to launch the YouTube app.

In the future there is a new API for Android for YouTube. But it has not been released. Theme again neither has Fragment support for Google Maps that was announced in Dec 2011. - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WFsx-u-q3Y

Pros/Cons below (Examples are all making the WebView fill 100% of screen height and width)

**WebView - IFrame** - Limited configuration available. Runs in the WebView and works on nearly all platforms. Don't get me wrong, sometimes different options do not work, and you get a grey background when you try to play the video. Use the following site to create the IFrame code and try different options until it works for you - https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo (Do note several of the allowed configuration options do not work, such as hide controls has no effect). As mentioned there are lots of different options so trial and error is involved. Whilst several don't work, some look quite different. Looking at your question, i've never used the html5=1 option before, or set youtube.com as the base url.

```
webView = new WebView(this);
webView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

// Prevent scrolling of the webview
webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); //Blank webview to prevent null pointer plugin issues
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});

String data = "<html>"+
"<head>"+
"</head>"+
"<body style=\"margin: 0; padding: 0\">"+
"<iframe " +
"type=\"text/html\" "+
"class=\"youtube-player\" "+
"width=\"100%25\" "+
"height=\"100%25\" "+
"src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/" + uri +
"?controls=0&showinfo=0&showsearch=0&modestbranding=1&fs=0\" "+
"frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>" +
"</body>"+
"</html>";

webView.loadData(data, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

**WebView - YouTube API** - Much better, but requires flash. Therefore "Nexus 7" and any future devices released with JellyBean (4.1 and above) will not work. As the WebView on those devices uses a cut down version of Chrome rather than a cut down version of WebBrowser. Therefore as I found out yesterday, going forward this can't be used on our apps.

```
webView = new WebView(this);
webView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

// Prevent scrolling of the webview
webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); //Blank webview to prevent null pointer plugin issues
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});

String data = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>" + "<html>" + "<body style=\"margin: 0; padding: 0\">"
+ "<div id=\"player\"></div>"
+ "<script>"
+
// Load player api asynchronously.
"var tag = document.createElement('script');" + "tag.src = \"http://www.youtube.com/player_api\";"
        + "var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];" + "firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);"
        + "var done = false;" + "var player;" + "function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {" + "player = new YT.Player('player', {" + "height: '100%25',"
        + "width: '100%25'," + "videoId: '"
        + uri
        + "',"
        + "playerVars: { 'controls': "
        + controls
        + ", 'showinfo': 0, 'fs':0, 'modestbranding':1 },"
        + "events: {"
        + "'onReady': onPlayerReady," + "'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange" + "}" + "});" + "}" + "function onPlayerReady(evt) {" +
        // Autoplay
        "evt.target.playVideo();" + "}" + "function onPlayerStateChange(evt) {" +
        "}" + "function stopVideo() {" + "player.stopVideo();" + "}" + "</script>" + "</body>" + "</html>";

webView.loadData(data, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

**VideoView - YouTube Data API** - Can get access to information and importantly links to the video streams for use in a VideoView. The draw back is the free API is limited to low quaility 3GP videos not the MP4 (high quality/HD) streams. - https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#data_api

**Intent - Launch YouTube** - Open the YouTube app with the video you want to play. Drawback is that another app is opened, thus not embedded into your app, and that some devices don't have YouTube installed.

```
if (AppChecker.isAppInstalled("com.google.android.youtube", this) == true)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:" + uri));
    startActivity(intent);
}
else
{
    //Show youtube not installed
}

//Code to check if YouTube is installed.

public class AppChecker
{
    public static boolean isAppInstalled(String uri, Activity activity)
    {
        PackageManager pm = activity.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
        boolean app_installed = false;
        try
        {
            pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            app_installed = true;
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
        {
            app_installed = false;
        }
        return app_installed;
    }
}
```

Comment: On the Nexus 7, We were getting a gray screen with a white image of a broken movie reel. `webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());` fixed the problem. thanks

Comment: I'm sure I tried that but it never helped. Ill have to give it ago when next back on the Android client. Cheers

Comment: Also, instead of `youtube.com/v/` we are using `youtbue.com/embed/` since that will use HTML5 instead of flash.

Comment: @JonWillis i tried your code but it doesn't help me . did you find any other solution for this?

Comment: @edwin, I haven't found any other ways yet. Preference has been more towards to launch the youtube application if installed, as it will handle many of the issues (i.e. playing a video, playing in background even if your app is closed, + more). One day Google will launch the YouTube control for android.